# Welcome message for per site metas is not able to localize

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, per-site-meta, localization, russian-stackoverflow

If you open any of localized meta site in browser's private mode, e.g. [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) you will see untranslated text on the top right corner:

> [image: Welcome]

This message is not found in Transifex, hence unable to localize.

Related bug report on ruSO.meta: [Отсутствует перевод блока приветствия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4079/176217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text and styling for that block are basically just HTML in the site's settings.

If y'all come up with a translation on SOru's meta, we can set that up.

Comment: True. It's already translated for Portuguese and Japanese. I did check ruSO and esSO only.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason to not move it into Transifex?

Comment: @alexolut Having a setting for this allows us to customize the box a lot easier, but I'm not sure off hand if there are any sites with different text there. We could probably do a default in code (and, by extension, in Transifex) with a site setting override. That has the potential to be confusing, though, since any Transifex changes would never get reflected on the site if there was an override present.

Comment: I did not really understand the part about confusing. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @alexolut I mean that if we were to have something custom in a setting that overrides the transifex string, making any changes in transifex wouldn't show up on the site, but it wouldn't be at all obvious why.

Comment: now I see. In my thoughts Transifex should contain maximum of possible settings for localized site. Any other place for settings should be used only in rare unique cases.